# How to make an vivid artificial peak in a specified place?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, filtering

I have a such graphics
[image]

which plot by this data,and its range of `x` is from 10 to 90 commonly:

```
data = (Uncompress@*FromCharacterCode@*
    Flatten@*(ImageData[#1, "Byte"] &)@*Import)[
  "http://ooo.0o0.ooo/2016/12/14/5850ba5019da8.png"];
```

I want make an artificial peak in some specified place,such as the red arrow point.
[image]

I can made it by *Photoshop*,but little troublesome:
[image]

But can I do it in *Mathematica*?

### Current try

```
range = Select[data, 42 < First[#] < 49 &];
gapData = Complement[data, range];
xpos = Round[Length[range]/2];
range[[xpos - 10 ;; xpos + 10]] = {range[[xpos, 1]], 2000};
range = Transpose[{First /@ range, MeanFilter[Last /@ range, 3]}];
smoothData = SortBy[Join[gapData, range], First];
ListLinePlot[smoothData, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

If I use `MeanFilter`,I will get a **little fat peak** sometimes,but actually it cannot be that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a simple `ReplacePart` is not sufficient here, you can define a function that uses a window to add a peak around a neighbourhood. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
ClearAll[addPeak]
addPeak[position_Integer, {size_, width_Integer}][data : {{_, _} ..}] /;
  ((position > width) && (position < (Length@data - width))) := 
  ReplacePart[data, 
   Table[q -> {data[[q, 1]], 
      data[[q, 2]] + size BartlettWindow[(q - position)/width]}, {q, 
     position - width, position + width}]];
addPeak[position_Integer, {size_, width_Integer}][data : {{_, _} ..}] := 
  data;
```

You can change `BartlettWindow` to any preset windowing function (or pass it on as an option).

Here's the result of adding a peak of magnitude 1000 at position 2025 of width 840 data points:

```
ListLinePlot[addPeak[2025, {1000, 420}][data], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and here is the result of adding a narrower peak of width 100 points and magnitude 4000 to the same point:

```
ListLinePlot[addPeak[2025, {4000, 50}][data], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Even if it's not precisely what you are looking for, it should get you started.

Comment: Maybe we should rescale that 2025 to `{10,90}`. :)

Comment: I don't quite understand? 2025 refers to the position of the centre of the peak

Comment: Yep,I got that.I mean,it is not easy to know that position is 2025.:)

Comment: Ah, I see now. Well, all you need is to call it like (if, say you want the peak at 45.): `addPeak[Sequence @@ First@Position[data, {45., _}], {4000, 50}][data]`